# How to register touch event cocos3d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos3d

I have tried to find a way of registering a touch event in cocos3d such as TOUCHESBEGAN but that does not exist, only

```
    -(void) touchEvent: (uint) touchType at: (CGPoint) touchPoint {
    NSLog(@"hello");
    }
```

Bu that does not log "hello".
How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are still interested with the answer, but here goes.

In order to use touchEvent in cocos3d, you need to enable touch in the **CC3Layer** (in the initializeControls method)

```
self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
```

Then you can use the touchEvent:(uint)touchType at:(CGPoint)touchPoint in the **CC3Scene**.

Answer (score 0):

Is started to work for me when I have put this code in my CC3Layer subclass

```
-(void) initializeControls {
    [self scheduleUpdate];
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self setTouchEnabled:YES];
}
```